How to make a Grid image generator in python?
So I'm looking to make a python program to generate a png image of a grid with desired rows and columns and desired size. If I were to put the size of the image as 1080x1920 and asked for a 6x5 grid, then I should get a result like this.

Please [edit] and share the code you wrote and the problems you face. I voted to close as "needs more focus".

Sounds like you'll want Pillow's ImageDraw.rectangle().

Did you google something like "python generate png"? Results should include tutorials like this one

Firstly install this library.
pip install Pillow

then use the below written code which Creates a blank image with a white background. Calculates the width and height of each cell based on the number of rows and columns. Draws horizontal and vertical lines to form the grid. Saves the image to a file named grid.png.
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

def create_grid_image(image_width, image_height, rows, cols, line_color=(0, 0, 0), line_width=2, output_path="grid.png"):
    # Create a blank image with white background
    image = Image.new("RGB", (image_width, image_height), "white")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    
    # Calculate the width and height of each cell
    cell_width = image_width / cols
    cell_height = image_height / rows
    
    # Draw the horizontal lines
    for row in range(1, rows):
        y = int(row * cell_height)
        draw.line([(0, y), (image_width, y)], fill=line_color, width=line_width)
    
    # Draw the vertical lines
    for col in range(1, cols):
        x = int(col * cell_width)
        draw.line([(x, 0), (x, image_height)], fill=line_color, width=line_width)
    
    # Save the image
    image.save(output_path)
    print(f"Grid image saved to {output_path}")

# Example usage
image_width = 1920
image_height = 1080
rows = 6
cols = 5

create_grid_image(image_width, image_height, rows, cols)

